# Add NSNumber 0 to NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsnumber, zero

I need to create a dictionary with for a search, based on IDs, but if no ID gets selected, 0 has to be stored.

Now I can obviously do it like this:

```
NSNumber* cityID;
NSNumber* zoneID; //These two do get value, just showing for their class
NSDictionary *cityDictionary = @{@"CityID": [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)cityId], @"CityZoneID": [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)zoneId]};
```

I feel it's really messy like that. It gets cast to `int`, then turned back to `NSNumber`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
NSDictionary *cityDictionary = @{
      @"CityID" :     (cityID == nil ? @0 : cityID),
      @"CityZoneID" : (zoneID == nil ? @0 : zoneID)
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
// May be syntax change but you need to initialise with zero first
NSNumber* cityID = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
NSNumber* zoneID = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0]; //Init with Zero then you can added value for this if no value default will be 0
NSDictionary *cityDictionary = @{@"CityID": [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)cityId], @"CityZoneID": [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)zoneId]};
```

This may help

Answer (score 1):

```
NSNumber* cityID;
NSNumber* zoneID;
if((cityID == nil)||(zoneID == nil))
{
    NSDictionary *cityDictionary = @{@"CityID": [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], @"CityZoneID": [NSNumber numberWithInt:0]};
}
```

Comment: If I'd go that route, I would need to make 4 if statements (both are good, A is good, B is good, neither are good).